# converting date to string and splitting day,month and year

Tags: python

Below is my table with date column as object datatype.
My agenda is to convert object into string datatype and split the date column into day, month and year.
I tried many ways but no luck.
Can someone help on this?

```
Date        x    y    z       a      b
09.05.2013  4   31  12472   199.0   1.0
25.12.2013  11  26  1856    1699.0  1.0
18.11.2014  22  25  15263   699.0   1.0
05.03.2015  26  28  5037    2599.0  1.0
14.10.2015  33  6   17270   199.0   1.0
```

Comment: Whats the expected output?

Comment: try mapping the list with `timedate.strptime` and getting the tokens out of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `pandas dataframe`, you could do as follows.

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)
df['Day'] = df['Date'].str[0:2]
df['Month'] = df['Date'].str[3:5]
df['Year'] = df['Date'].str[6:]
df
```

which gives you the following output.

```
    Date    x   y   z   a   b   Day     Month   Year
0   09.05.2013  4   31  12472   199.0   1.0     09  05  2013
1   25.12.2013  11  26  1856    1699.0  1.0     25  12  2013
2   18.11.2014  22  25  15263   699.0   1.0     18  11  2014
3   05.03.2015  26  28  5037    2599.0  1.0     05  03  2015
4   14.10.2015  33  6   17270   199.0   1.0     14  10  2015
```

Comment: Francis can u explain str[0:2]

Comment: `str[0:2]` means, substring the string value, starting from index `0` till index `2`, but excluding index `2`